# jquery, check if check box is checked with a variable having id of the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<#list courseGroup as eachCourse>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="${eachCourse}" type="checkbox" onClick="javascript:getBatchNos('${eachCourse}');"> <label for="${eachCourse}">${eachCourse}</label>
        </td>
     <tr>   
</#list>

function getBatchNos(course) {

   // I dont have id of the element to check if it is checked
   // variable course is holding the actual Id of the element
   // Please help me how I would be able to access this element using variable course   

   if (jQuery("#course").is(":checked")) { 

   }        

}
```

I want to find out if check box is checked or unchecked with a variable having id of the checkbox. If it is not possible please suggest me if there is any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a variable in that looks like your ID, so why not use that?

```
function getBatchNos(course) {

   // I dont have id of the element to check if it is checked
   // variable course is holding the actual Id of the element
   // Please help me how I would be able to access this element using variable course   

   if (jQuery("#"+course).is(":checked")) { 

   }        

}
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the super quick response. That works. I am having a big list of courses that keep changing. so, its hard to access each element by id.